# 'Cannot overwrite `User` model once compiled.' using typescript, mongoose and lambda function

Tags: typescript, mongoose, lambda

I'm pretty sure I'm getting this error because of the way I am importing and exporting the mongoose schemas, and I've done this in Node but trying to convert my code into TypeScript has given me some growing pains.

Initial run works completely fine, and I get the GraphQL playground that I'm looking for. However if I modify my codebase even in the slightest, I get the error in the title.

models\User.ts

```
import { Schema, Document, Model, model } from 'mongoose';

export interface IUser extends Document {
    name: string;
    email: string;
    password: string;
}

//Create Schema
const UserSchema: Schema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

export const User: Model<IUser> = model<IUser>('User', UserSchema);
```

models\index.ts

```
import { User } from "./User";

export default {
    User
};
```

lambda\graphql.ts

```
import { ApolloServer, AuthenticationError } from "apollo-server-lambda";
import "reflect-metadata";
import resolvers from "../resolvers";
import schemas from "../schema";
import * as mongoose from "mongoose";
import { verify } from "jsonwebtoken";
import models from "../models";
import { MONGODB_URI, SECRET } from "../utils/constants";

export interface IToken extends Document {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

//validate jwt then set me in graphql server context
const getMe = async (token: any) => {

  if (token) {
    try {
      const user = await verify(token, SECRET)
      return user;
    } catch (e) {
      throw new AuthenticationError("Your Session expired. Sign in again.");
    }
  }
  return null;
};


const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs: schemas,
  resolvers,
  context: async ({ event }) => {
    const user = await getMe(event.headers.authorization);
    return {
      models,
      me: user,
      secret: SECRET
    }
  }
});

mongoose
  .connect(MONGODB_URI, { 'useUnifiedTopology': true, 'useNewUrlParser': true })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("mongodb connected");
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });

exports.handler = server.createHandler({
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
    credentials: true
  }
});
```

I suspect it's the way that I've imported in models\index.ts? What am I missing?

Comment: Did you use the solution mannieschumpert suggested or did you find another way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very late response, but this isn't too hard to solve. In your export statement, you have to check for an existing model, and either export that or the model as defined.

Here's the non-typed way:

```
export const User = mongoose.models.User || mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Comment: Hey @mannieschumpert do you think you can explain why was this happening and how you found this solution?